# Angular 9 : php a RESTful CRUD API with HttpClient

Tags: php, angular, curl, httpclient

l have following php module

uAPIwork.php

```
    <?php $___notjson=1; header('Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8');
    
    
     require 'uAPImodule.php';
     $request = new Request(array(
        'oauth_consumer_key'    => 'check',
        'oauth_consumer_secret' => 'fkFNhdbbRENO1GQilHxWvO86QabO6g',
        'oauth_token'           => 'OfTW8pDo1aIjNvHOdv.nRbZAER5x.LRndWwltepI',
        'oauth_token_secret'    => '6bnfzAGvMpHpJF1gs9XWqSWGBAdAzdXJWxAj1S..'
        ));
     $response = $request->get('/news', array(
    //различные параметры, если нужно
        ));
        json_encode($response); //Получаем ответ
        print_r($response);
        ?>
```

Home.ts

```
     request(){
    
     this.http
               .get('assets/uAPIwork.php')
               .subscribe(res=>{console.log(res)});
    
    
      }
```

When i run the code ,  i have following error:
`HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/uAPIwork.php", ok: false, …}`

any solution please ?

Comment: is this API yours? I mean are your debugging the API or the Angular http call?

Comment: Angular http call

Comment: So its working say through Postman? If so then there is a bit more to do Angular side and more than is practical here. I would suggest you complete the Google Tour of Heroes Tutorial for information on setting up http via a service. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6